# How many ways are there to put 5 identical balls into 2 different boxes?

Tags: probability, combinations

The only way I know how to solve this problem is by drawing a table: Making $6$ the answer.

```
Number of balls in the box:
First Box.......Second Box
5........................0
4........................1
3........................2
2........................3
1........................4
0........................5
```

But how can we solve it mathematically?

Comment: I'd say this is more than enough. No reason to make it fancier or more advanced than it is.

Comment: True, but what if the question said something such as putting 100 identical balls into 2 different boxes? It would take a very long time to draw a list.

Comment: Put $n$ identical balls into $2$ different boxes... Well for the number of balls in the first box there are $n+1$ possibilities, right?

Comment: @Jason You're right. In that case it would take rather more space than necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $k$ identical balls and $2$ different boxes, your argument gives $k+1$ possibilities.

With $k$ identical balls and $n$ different boxes, a [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) argument gives ${k+n-1 \choose n-1}$ possibilities.